# Firefox Sync Enabled

Tags: firefox

Is it possible to use Firefox Sync to sync bookmarks in Tor? I have set indentity.fxaccounts.enabled to true, but it still seems to not work. Is there any way to do this, or is it consideredf a security risk?

Using Ubuntu

Thanks,

Steve

Comment: Besides what the previous person said which is true, that functionality is simply not in Tor Browser.

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend this. Use a separate Firefox if you really want to do that.

Obviously, sync runs on your local machine, thereby exposing your real identity

Answer (score 0):

Per https://forum.torproject.net/t/how-to-enable-firefox-account-sync/7735/2?u=rokejulianlockhart, convert `identity.fxaccounts.enabled` from `false` to `true` in [`start-tor-browser`](https://askubuntu.com/a/985202/1002900) `about:config`.

However, the synchronization functionality itself isn't necessarily entirely operative yet/anymore.